# Showing $x''=|x|$ changes signal

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $x$ be a solution for the differential equation $x''=|x|$. I want to show that if $x(t_0)$ is zero it changes signal around that point. I don't have much idea on what to do.

Comment: Do you mean changes sign?

Comment: If the solution did not change sign at a root, then it would have to be the zero function from the start.

Comment: Also, strictly speaking, we could have $x'' = |x|$ and $x(t_0) =0$ without changing sign there if $x(t) = 0$ for all $t$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

I would solve the ODE for both cases where $x<0$ (you should get trig functions) and $x > 0$ (you should get exponential families). Then when $x=0$, the form of the solution would change, showing change of signal.

Comment: I believe you have the $x>0$ and $x < 0$ cases swapped.

Comment: @eyeballfrog fixed thanks